# Callout from scheduled Apex not supported

Tags: apex, scheduled-apex, callout, future

I am trying to call a future method from my scheduled apex but it is giving this error message

Scheduled class

```
global class Scheduledbacthfuture Implements Schedulable{

public Interface IScheduleDispached{
    void execute(SchedulableContext sc);
}

global void execute(SchedulableContext sc){
    Type targetType = Type.forName('HANDLERNAME');
    if(targetType != null){
        IScheduleDispached obj = (IScheduleDispached)targetType.newInstance();
        obj.execute(sc);
    }
}
}
```

Handler

```
 public class HANDLERNAME implements Scheduledbacthfuture.IScheduleDispached           
 {

  public void execute(SchedulableContext sc)
   {
    //Call your Future Method Here
   List<User> newusers = [Select Id,CFS_Activation_Date__c from user where (Profile.Name='CTCT Solution Provider (Login Based)'OR Profile.Name='CTCT Solution Provider (Named)')AND lmscons__Cornerstone_ID__c=NULL AND lmscons__CFS_Status__c='Not CFS user']; 
    if(newusers.size()>0)
    System.debug(newusers.size()+' new users found will give them license in a sometime');

   if(newusers.size()>0)
   {
    UserHandler.convertListToSet(newusers);
  // lmscons.ConsumerUserWebservice.CreateConsumerUsers(newusers, false); 
   }

 } 

 }
```

> FATAL_ERROR System.CalloutException: Callout from scheduled Apex not
>   supported.

Comment: Please share your code.

Comment: UserHandler.convertListToSet(newusers); calls a class which calls a future method with @future(callout=true) tag

Comment: Just simply remove the @future annotation and it will work. As schedulable execution is of Async nature, it can make the callout in the same execution without any future annotation.

Comment: I am using this signature currently @future(callout=true) I think I would try it once without this

Comment: See e.g. http://salesforceravisharma.blogspot.ie/2016/04/webservice-callout-from-scheduled-apex.html.